# AWS SAM Lambda - Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'requests', 'msal' . pipeline using Azure CI/CD

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, azure-devops, sam

I created a python project using AWS lambda using SAM template. Created virtual environment and installed all required modules. for example, requests, msal etc. module names mentioned in requirements.txt file and installed. I am able to build, debug and deploy using sam command from my vscode. for example. sam build, sam local invoke , sam deploy --guided command.

As a project repo uses Azure devOps. Now, I created project pipeline and deployed to AWS successfully.

part of pipeline script -(install dependencies)

- script: |
  python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  pip install -r src/requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'

When I tested lambda function from AWS console or call url, It show the following error as per cloud watch log. It shows module not found "request" and "msal".
for example.
ERROR: Function Logs
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'requests'

python 3.9

AWS SAM

Azure devOps repo

VScode

I am unable to figure out the issue. I spent time but did not find the cause. I am stuck. Please give me hints/ideas/solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the following answer. It might help someone.

```yaml
- task: AWSShellScript@1
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: AwsServiceConnection
    regionName: 'us-east-1'
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: |
      sam build --debug \
      --template-file template.yaml

- task: AWSShellScript@1
  displayName: 'Package'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: AwsServiceConnection
    regionName: us-east-1
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: |
      sam package  --resolve-s3  --output-template-file packaged.yaml

- task: AWSShellScript@1
  displayName: 'Deploy Infrastructure'
  inputs:
      awsCredentials: AwsServiceConnection
      regionName: 'us-east-1'
      scriptType: "inline"
      inlineScript: |
        sam deploy \
        --template-file packaged.yaml \
        --no-confirm-changeset \
        --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
        --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM  \
        --stack-name sam-test-stack \
        --resolve-s3 \
        --s3-prefix sam-test-stack
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda dependencies have to be installed at the root folder. See the "Deployment package with dependencies" Section, Step 5 in this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html).

> Create a deployment package with the installed library at the root.

You can do so by going to the root directory, then issue a `pip install` with a `-t` (target) flag and specifying the current directory with a dot `.`.

`pip install -r src/requirements.txt -t .`

Comment: Thank you @Register Sole for your response. It does not work. same error message.

Comment: @Morshed Did you verify that in the zip that is deployed, the installed library is in the root folder?

Comment: I used the SAM command to build and deploy in pipeline because the same command works from development. SAM Build command : - task: AWSShellScript@1
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    awsCredentials: AwsServiceConnection
    regionName: $(REGION)
    scriptType: 'inline'
    inlineScript: |
      sam build --debug \
      --template-file template.yaml

Comment: SAM deploy command: - task: AWSShellScript@1
  displayName: 'Deploy Infrastructure'
  inputs:
      awsCredentials: AwsServiceConnection
      regionName: $(REGION)
      scriptType: "inline"
      inlineScript: |
        sam deploy \
        --template-file template.yaml \
        --no-confirm-changeset \
        --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
        --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM  \
        --stack-name test-sam-hw-stack \
        --s3_bucket $(TEST_S3_BUCKET) \
        --s3-prefix test-sam-hw-stack

Comment: Sam deploy should create a zip file because same deploy command used in vscode and it automatically deploy to AWS but not working from Azure pipeline.